# How toconvert multiple one-dimensional json to one multidimensional?

Tags: python, json

Hello help me please friends!
I have:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Zach But",
        "article": "Article_1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Zach But",
        "article": "Article_2"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Ann Spring",
        "article": "Article_3"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Ann Spring",
        "articles": "Article_4"
    }
  ]
```

Need result:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Zach But",
        "article": [
                    "Article_1",
                    "Article_2"
                   ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Ann Spring",
        "article": [
                    "Article_3",
                    "Article_4"
                   ]
    }
  ]
```

That is, I have duplicate data on authors who have different articles, and I need to add these articles to each of the authors so that the authors do not repeat themselves. Please tell me how to do it right.

```
f = open('authors_test.json')
data = json.load(f)
for i in range(0, len(data)):

    if data[i]['name'] == data[i-1]['name']:
    # dont know
```

I can load json from a file and compare objects by author name, but I don’t know how to further implement what I need so that I end up with one object with each author, which has an array of articles

Answer (score 0):

You can write a python code where if the JSON values `name` are equal, append the `article value` to an `articles array`

Code:

```
newarr = []
for i in range(1, len(arr)):
    if arr[i].name == arr[i-1].name:
        newarr[i].append(arr[i].article)
        newarr[i].append(arr[i].name)
        newarr[i].append(arr[i].id)
```

Comment: I edit my post, see please and help me friend